# Create djvu from jpeg - best practices and tutorial?

Tags: mathematical-software

This is definitely not a mathematical question, but a relevant one I believe. There are incomplete versions of some books floating around the web and I want to put in the missing pages. There is a good book scanner at our university, albeit I have not really understood most of its functions yet. At the moment I am able to scan color JPGs. So I've got a batch of color JPGs, what next should I do? I want a djvu file.

I have tried cpaldjvu from [djvulibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/), but it seems to hang up on one single jpg. (Size 2MB.) Some people recommend passing through PDF, but this looks like a lot of overhead work to me. Is there a good tutorial for non-experts? (For Windows or Ubuntu - but bear with an Ubuntu noob who barely knows how to install packages. I am able, however, to script a few lines in bash.)

Besides, is pre-processing of the JPGs in a graphics editor helpful? Is it of use to cut out the margins, or are they useful for the DJVU encoder to approximate the background color?

PS. I think I know how to split DJVU files into pieces and reassemble them. I am only interested in JPG->DJVU here.

Comment: It seems djvulibre includes another encoder, cjb2. Have you tried it? http://www.howtoforge.com/creating_djvu_documents_on_linux

Comment: Not an expert either, but people who helped me in making nice DjVus have shown me ScanKromsator: http://www.djvu-soft.narod.ru/kromsator/eng.htm ; it might be of use to you!

Comment: I usually reencode the images to pbm (for black/white books) using imagemagick (batch processing this is easy using imagemagick, just read the documentation), then encode all of the pages to djvu individually using djvulibre.  The last step is to compile them into a book, which you have to script, but this is honestly not difficult.  For cropping/recentering/etc, I found a program called ScanTailor, which iirc is only for Windows, but it is really great and worth checking out.

Comment: To clarify, Scan Tailor does batch fixes on pages, including removing dark spots around the margins, recentering pages, fixing distortion from bad scanning, despeckling, etc.

Comment: I think that this is off topic.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning ScanKromsator! Now time to read some manuals for me...

Comment: @Alberto: cjb2 wants a bitonal tiff. I fear that if I blindly convert the color images to B/W, much is lost. If greyscale would work...

Comment: @Andrew: of course it is. But it is a question that I think others here have dealt with, probably more so than on StackOverflow.

Comment: Bolega (SK's author) was very nice when I had asked him questions on how to properly use his tool; if after reading the manual you're still stuck, you can try contacting him.

Comment: Darij, I don't consider that a sufficient argument for this question to be asked here.  But then I'm considered quite "hard line" in what I consider acceptable so don't take it personally!

Comment: I agree that this is off topic and belongs on a different forum.

Comment: I echo Andrew and Akhil -- it is off topic.

Comment: @darij: you can use imagemagick to encode to pgm instead of pbm, which preserves grayscale information.  The rest of what I said works the same way.

Comment: Meta discussion: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/620/create-djvu-from-jpeg (apologies for not posting the link earlier)

Answer (score 3):

You could write a simple script that converts your images to PDF using [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), concatenates the resulting files using [pdftk](http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/) and finally, converts the single PDF file obtained in that way to DjVu using [pdf2djvu](http://pdf2djvu.googlecode.com/). I had skipped the part where you said you wanted to avoid the PDF step, but I hope this will come in handy if you change your mind.

By the way, if you're using Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install imagemagick pdftk pdf2djvu